# How to make dropdown's menu use full width when mobile only?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

So what I'm trying to do is to use full width / 100vw when you are seeing it from a mobile.

[image: This is how it sees]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: This is how I want it to be]

I'm trying to acomplish that without using any javascript/jquery. Is it possible?
Let me tell you I didnt use extra css I only use menu and dropdown in it.

Comment: Please provide working code or any link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this css in mobile media query:

```
.ui.menu .item.marginless {
  position: static;
}
.ui.dropdown .menu.notifications {
  left: 0 !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ankita, how do I make the other menu wide aswell?

Comment: Which menu have you talked about it...?

Comment: Nothing. Thanks I did it :)